# Guice binding a parent concrete class separately from child

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying set up a Guice Module that will allow me to inject a parent class if the field has a certain annotation and a child class if the field does *not* have that annotation. Both the parent and child are concrete classes. What I have so far is:

```
bind(Key.get(Parent.class, MyAnnotation.class)).to(Parent.class);
bind(Parent.class).to(Child.class);
```

When I do this, I still seem to get an instance of the `Child` class even when I inject with the annotation. I believe the problem is that Guice sees from the first binding that it needs an instance of `Parent`. But then when it goes to provide the instance, it finds a binding for `Parent` (without an annotation) and uses it, resulting in a `Child` instance still being created. Is there a way to get around this problem?

FWIW, I have discovered that I can get around this by switching which gets the annotation. But for simplicity's sake, I'd prefer to have the Parent be the one that's provided when there's an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out this *was* the issue. The way I got around this is by binding the Parent class with the annotation using a constructor. This avoids the circular binding dependency.

```
bind(Parent.class).to(Child.class);

Constructor<?>[] parentConstructors = Parent.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
checkArgument(parentConstructors.length == 1); // Since I only have an @Inject constructor, I can use that
Constructor<Parent> parentConstructor = (Constructor<Parent>) parentConstructors[0];
bind(Key.get(Parent.class, MyAnnotation.class)).toConstructor(parentConstructor);
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at `TypeListener` and `TypeEncounter` which you can use to do this type of injection based on annotation.